# Execute SQL*Plus from PowerShell

Tags: powershell, call, sqlplus

I got two files in `C:\temp\SQL\alex.sql` and in `C:\temp\alex.ps1`.

In `C:\temp\SQL\alex.sql`, that is simply

```
select count(*) from user_tables;
quit;
```

In `C:\temp\alex.ps1`, that is

```
$cmd = "sqlplus";
$args = "user/password@server/sid @C:\temp\SQL\alex.sql";
&$cmd $args;
```

I tried the command in Command Prompt

`sqlplus user/password@server/sid @C:\temp\SQL\alex.sql` which executed perfectly!

The SQL file is not executed at all, but **SQL*Plus help** is shown.

What did I do wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself

I use `cmd.exe /c` and `alex.ps1` is now

```
$cmd = "cmd.exe";
$args = "/c sqlplus user/password@server/sid @C:\temp\SQL\alex.sql";
&$cmd $args;
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Could you please share why you did that?

Answer (score 1):

To offer an alternative solution to @Alex Yeung, you can simply use the PowerShell `&` call command to run the statement outright, without the need to use `cmd.exe`:

```
&sqlplus user/password@server @C:\path\script.sql
```

Consider adding the following to the bottom of your script file to ensure SQLPlus is closed when it has finished running:

```
DISCO -- Disconnect
EXIT -- Exit SQLPlus
```