# How to Execute a SQL Oracle script (create table) through Powershell

Tags: sql, oracle, powershell

The title says it all really, I have been trying to execute a SQL Oracle script through PowerShell, but it is not working. I am not getting an error, it just says 'running script/selection' at the bottom right hand corner. However I do not think it is correctly connecting to Oracle.

Please see the code in the .ps1 file:

```
sqlplus Username\Password "@C:\Users\...\script1.sql"
```

In the sql script there is:

```
CREATE TABLE DEPT 
(
  DEPTNO VARCHAR2(20) 
, DNAME VARCHAR2(20) 
, LOC VARCHAR2(20) 
);
```

Comment: The link mentioned here explains everything clearly. Just folow it. https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/using-powershell-to-generate-table-creation-scripts/

Comment: There are a number of questions on this site which are similar. Have you seen these questions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9627225/execute-sqlplus-from-powershell, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24682465/how-to-run-a-sql-plus-script-in-powershell

Comment: I had see these links before, but thank you for posting: The solution which I later discovered was: `sqlplus -s database/password@$pathtoscript`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
sqlplus <<UserName>>/<<Password>>@<<Database>> @"<<ScriptFilePath>>"
```

Database should be tnsnames.ora entry. You can use the following directly.